# VBA can't run the python script on the new PC

Tags: python, vba

This code starts the python script from VBA, and it worked well on my old PC.

```
    Sub py_launcher_8()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Long

        errorCode = wsh.Run("C:/Users/belose/PycharmProjects/week2/venv/Scripts/python.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\week2\VGM\VGM_eval.py", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

        If errorCode = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
        Else
            MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then I had to move to another PC, where python is located in anaconda environment: C:\Users\belose\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe

```
    Sub py_launcher_8()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Long

        errorCode = wsh.Run("C:\Users\belose\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\DRM\venv\VGM\VGM_eval.py", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

        If errorCode = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
        Else
            MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
        End If
    End Sub
```

The VBA now doesn't start the python script and returns error code 1.

The python script itself is OK.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a `test.py` script with `print ("Hello World..!!")` and run it to check the if the problem is due to path of `python.exe` or execution of `python script`.

if it is running then you should check your python script and if not then you should verify the `python.exe` path.

To Locate the python path you may use the following steps:

1. From the Start Menu open the `Anaconda Prompt`.
2. If you want the location of a Python interpreter for a conda environment other than 
   the root conda environment, run `activate environment-name`.
3. Run `where python`.

Comment: It proved out that some libraries were missing in the environment. Thanks!